# Not able to get desired font style when applied

Tags: html, css

I was reading a book called **CSS: the Definitive Guide. (2017)** I came across this code `p {font: medium Helvetica;}`. The code doesn't seem to work.

I have create a similar code below:

```css
h1 {
  font: bold monospace;
}
```

```html
<h1>Full Stack Developer</h1>
```

As you can see in the code, the font style doesn't change to monospace. I fixed the issue by adding size of `30px` after `bold`

**Code below after adding `30px`**

```css
h1 {
  font: medium 30px monospace;
}
```

```html
<h1>Full Stack Developer</h1>
```

Was there a mistake in the book, or is there something I should know?

Comment: I actually asked another user that edited the question. But for the sake of this topic, your edit to change it to medium DOES take effect as seen. So I changed it back to bold because you have couple of answers already addressing that issue.

Comment: @ikiK definitely! i should have noticed! thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS `font` is a shorthand for these values

1. font-style
2. font-variant
3. font-weight
4. font-size/line-height
5. font-family

if you want to get the desired output, you have to use The `font-size` and `font-family`. these 2 values are required. If one of the other values is missing, their default value is used. or you can use separately.

Answer (score 1):

Your value is not legal.  It must include the font size according to MDN.

> If font is specified as a shorthand for several font-related
> properties, then:
>
> it must include values for: font-size, font-family

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font

Answer (score 0):

The font shorthand must include `font-family` and `font-size`, see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font). Your code is missing a `font-size` value like `medium` or `16px` because `bold` is a `font-weight`.

```css
h1 {
  font: medium monospace;
}
```

```html
<h1>Full Stack Developer</h1>
```

Comment: There's no mistake in the book. `medium` is a font size.

Comment: @Alohci yes, but it doesn't apply Helvetica font style

Comment: @coder3332 Medium is a font size. Bold is not a font size, it is a font weight. Huge difference.

Comment: @tacoshy yes! your right! :)but  if i put medium instead of bold, i still don't get the result!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `font` attribute in CSS, you must insert `font-size` and `font-family` inside.
It can include `font-style`, `font-variant`, `font-weight`, `font-stretch` and `font-height`.